# Sencha Touch: List and formfeilds on same view

Tags: forms, list, extjs, touch, field

I need to develop a view in Sencha Touch where some form fields, textarea & button have to be put just after a list; following is the source code:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyNotes',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'admissionnotes',

    requires: [
        'myapp.view.MyAppTitle',
        'myapp.view.MyList',
        'myapp.view.MyForm',
        'myapp.view.MyAppTabBar'
    ],

    config: {
            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true,
            scrollable: true,
        items: [
            {
               xtype: 'myapptitle'
            },
            {
               xtype: 'myapplist'
            },
            {
               xtype: 'myform'
            },
            {
               xtype: 'myapptabbar'
            }

            ]
    }
});
```

The problem is that these form fields are overlapping my list. Can somebody assist to resolve this isssue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `vbox` layout would be more appropriated than `fit`?

```
layout: {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch'}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'll try this out.

As a workaround, I've defined the _docked_ config of form field to _bottom_:
`
                 {
                  xtype: 'myform',
                  docked: 'bottom'
                 }
`